# Node.js - Sharing variables between different files

Tags: node.js, variables, sharing

I am new here and pretty new to Node.js. I got Express working fine, connecting to MySQL (database) is going fine, and socket io is working fine.

But I decided to split many of these features up in separated files. To keep my main JS file nice and clean. I made it possible to get variables from other js files back to my main.js script. Either using exports, or global. I find global working easier since most of them are functions. It's all working fine to this point.

But now the issue that I am having. I'm loading 3 js files in my main.js file. I am requiring the first js file, I call the function that is in that js file and store the result in a variable. That's going fine. But now the second js file is suppose to use or grab this variable, and that isn't working.

My question is, how do I make that work?

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of your design.

You should use `module.exports` to return a variable from a file.

**Example:**

file1.js

```
function someFunction() {return true;}
module.exports = someFunction();
```

main.js

```
console.log(require('./file.js')); // true
```

So, if the second file depends on the variable from the first file, you may also `require` the `file1.js` in the second one.

Or, export a function that accept one parameter in the second file. The main file should then use the variable from first file to call the function.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. Now that I can perform queries in other pages, and actually use queries for the first time, I come to realize that MySQL library is so unhandy. I come from PHP, where you can use a query and fetch the result and use it anywhere and anytime you like. But this library in Node.js works differently. Like so: mysql.query(query, function(err, rows, fields){ .... }); Now I wanna take the rows/results out of that function there, but it's quite troublesome. Any solution for that? I am not used to this jquery-style javascript.

Comment: Figured partly out why it is that I cannot get rows-data from the mysql query function. When the function is being called, nodejs is just going further with the script while the mysql query function is run async, so in the background kinda. - This is kinda ruining my plan of caching certain mysql results in the memory of node js, unless there is a way to work around it... I think I have a way, to set, or change value of a variable once the query is done. As long as it's not done, keep looping (with some timeout in between) certain functions. Until that one variable has given the green light.